# iOS devices & 2D space

Tags: ios, ipad, accelerometer, sensors

Am stuck on solving this problem. Say I have 2 ipads placed as shown in the figure. How does iPad 1 (one on left) know that iPad 2 (one on right) is to its right? Can I find this relative positioning?

Any change in relative positions of the 2 iPads should be communicated amongst them in real-time. To simplify matters I am only interested in 2D space (i.e. x,y)

I tried using GPS but it is not accurate enough. What sensor signal is appropriate here? Or should I consider a mix of multiple sensor signals? If so how?

Any related ideas are welcome.

[image]

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: this got me thinking - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WEjV1mYHlE

Comment: Moreover I think its a cool problem since If i am able to figure out this info about the relative positioning of lets say 2 ipads I can find a number of use cases eg. gaming, comine 2 or more ipads to form a bigger screen etc.

Comment: This isn't possible. In the video you mentioned, the position of the two iPads is either fixed or manually configurable.

Comment: yes in the video it is "either fixed or manually configurable". But I slightly expanded the problem & wanted to figure out if its possible to find positioning when its non-fixed using the multiple sensors on-board the iPad

Comment: I have to correct myself: The specific arrangement that is shown in the video actually _can_ be detected with the magnetometer (you can try it for example with [this app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/magnetometer/id342782714)), but you can't distinguish between other arrangements with this method. Of course this also requires that there aren't any other strong magnetic fields nearby.

Comment: what you want it can be done...but its insanely complicated. So..you can do this like so: distance between devices (aka distance between Bluetooth antennas) + accelerometer data (position of device). That being said..you can't do this with normal libraries (cuz you need the absolute exact power of the Bluetooth antennas) and i don't think you can find that out. The only plausible way is desktop-extend like functionality..when you set the distance and orientation manually..and there are apps already that do this

Comment: Did you try my idea/answer? Did it work?

Comment: @jhabbott i loved your idea. but i am still thinking through it. will get back to you with some Q's since it looks like you have put in some thought into this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long shot, but it might just work!

Examining my iPad2, I notice that the microphone is in the middle at the top and the speaker is on the bottom right. This means the distance from the left iPad's speaker to the right iPad's microphone is smaller than the distance from the right iPad's speaker to the left iPad's microphone.

Playing a sound (potentially an inaudible high-frequency sound) from one iPad and listening for it on the other, then telling the first iPad over the network that the sound was heard will give you a round-trip time. Performing this the other way around will give you another round-trip time. Doing this a number of times will give you average round-trip times from each iPad, which should statistically minimize the effects of any fluctuations in network/Bluetooth latency.

The iPad with the shortest round-trip time is the one on the left. Of course if the iPads are different models and the microphone/speakers are located in different places this will need to be taken into account. It could get pretty complicated, but it might work :)